# Extract variable but not function from JavaScript by Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract variables (with dot notation) but not functions from a string of JavaScript using Regex. This is what I have done so far.

```
var regex = /([_a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+(?:\.)?)+/g;
```

However, this regex will also extract JavaScript functions. For example,

```
var regex = /([_a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+(?:\.)?)+/g;
console.log("a.b.c(d.e) === f".match(regex));
```

will output

```
["a.b.c", "d.e", "f"]
```

but I am expecting

```
["d.e", "f"]
```

Comment: are you trying to get the params of a "function fromat string"?

Comment: Why not just do `console.log("a.b.c(d.e) === f".match(regex).slice(-2));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the end of the match, you can negative lookahead for `(`, to ensure that the captured substring is not a function call. Also negative lookahead for any of the characters in the same initial character set to make sure that the backtracking from a failed function match doesn't match part of the function substring:

```js
var regex = /([\w[\]]+\.?)+(?![.\w[\]]|\s*\()/g;
console.log("a.b.c(d.e) === f + q[w]e && obj[prop]()".match(regex));
```

It would probably be better to repeat groups of `.` followed by word characters, or `[` followed by word characters and `]`:

```js
var regex = /\w+(?:\.\w+|\[\w+\])+(?![([\].])/g;
console.log("a.b.c(d.e) === f + q[w].e && obj[prop]()".match(regex));
```

`\w+(?:\.\w+|\[\w+\])+(?![([\].])` means:

- `\w+` - Word characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]+`)
- `(?:\.\w+|\[\w+\])+` - Repeat either:

  - `\.\w+` - A `.` followed by word characters, or
  - `\[\w+\]` - `[`, followed by word characters, followed by `]`
- `(?![([\].])` - At the end of the pattern, negative lookahead for `(`, `[`, `]`, and `.`